# Retornar 0 quando o SUM for NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quando não acha resultados me retorna `NULL`, como posso fazer para a pesquisa me retornar 0 quando for `NULL`?

```
SELECT SUM(coluna1 + coluna2 + coluna3) 
 FROM table WHERE nome='funalo' AND MONTH(data) = 09 AND YEAR(data) = 2018
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(COALESCE(coluna1, 0) + COALESCE(coluna2, 0) + COALESCE(coluna3, 0)) FROM table WHERE nome='funalo' AND MONTH(data) = 09 AND YEAR(data) = 2018`

Comment: Veja se é isso que você precisa

Comment: Me volta null do mesmo jeito :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use IFNULL().

> Definição e uso:
>   A função IFNULL() permite retornar um valor alternativo se uma expressão for NULL. Se a expressão for NOT NULL, a função IFNULL() retornará a expressão. Fonte: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(coluna1 + coluna2 + coluna3), 0)
FROM table
WHERE nome='funalo' AND MONTH(data) = 09 AND YEAR(data) = 2018
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou muito obrigado Brother :]

Answer (score 5):

Basta colocar um `IFNULL` na sua consulta:

```
SELECT  IFNULL(SUM(coluna1 + coluna2 + coluna3), 0) AS Soma
FROM    table 
WHERE   nome        = 'funalo' 
    AND MONTH(data) = 09 
    AND YEAR(data)  = 2018
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou :[

Comment: Sorry, é MySql, não reparei, erro meu. Resposta editada.